# empty data from input fields which are enabled in the div

Tags: jquery

I have 4 input boxes in separate p tag.p tag is in div with id. Now When I click cancel button 3 input boxes values should get clear except one input box value which is in disabled mode.

I tried writing

```
    $('#edit-login :input').each(function () {
        id = this.id;
        console.log("#" + id);
        console.log(this.value);
        $(this).val('');
    });
```

But it's clearing input box value which is also disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if it's disabled. And don't proceed for that input.

```
$('#edit-login :input').each(function () {
    // If it's disabled, come out.
    if ($(this).prop("disabled"))
        return false;

    id = this.id;
    console.log("#" + id);
    console.log(this.value);
    $(this).val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to clean up your css selector. You can combine :not and :disable to get your result.

```js
$('#edit-login input:not(:disabled)').val('')
```

```html
<div id="edit-login">
  <p>
    <input type="text" value="stuff">
    <input type="text" value="stuff" >
    <input type="text" value="stuff" >
    <input type="text" value="stuff" disabled>
  </p>
</div
```